# How do I make my function return different results depending on type it's been called using templates in C++

Tags: c++, templates, casting, return, return-type

I've been looking for quite a while for an answer to my question, but couldn't find anything that worked.

Basically, I have a Binary Search Tree and a Search function:

```
T BinarySearchTree::Search(Node *tree, int key) const {
    if (tree == nullptr) // if root is null, key is not in tree
        return false;
    if (key == tree->key) // key is found
        return true;
    else if (key < tree->key) // recursively look at left subtree if key < tree->key
        return Search<T>(tree->left, key);
    else // recursively look at right subtree if key > tree->key
        return Search<T>(tree->right, key);
}
```

I want to return different things based on what type it's being called with. E.g. if I call the function as `Search<bool>()`, I want it to return true or false, but if I call `Search<Node*>`, I want it to return a pointer. It should kind of look like this:

```
T BinarySearchTree::Search(Node *tree, int key) const {
    if (key == tree->key){  // key is found
       if(T = bool)
            return true;
       else if(T = Node*)
           return tree;
       else if (T = int)
           return tree->key;
}
```

I'm not even sure if templates are the right way to go here, but any tips for implementation would be appreciated.

Comment: why not simply two different functions? one called `find` the other called `getNode` ?

Comment: `std::variant` with a lot of setup work. And I *strongly* urge you to consider that, whatever mysterious problem this is *really* supposed to be solving, this is *not* likely to be a good way to solve it.

Comment: or why do you need the one returning `true` or `false` in the first place? Isnt it doing basically the same (search the tree for `key`) ? You can use a `nullptr` to indicate that the key was not found then you get both in one call

Comment: (1) Overloading based on return type, while possible, is almost universally a bad idea — make two different functions (one can be implemented in terms of the other, so you don’t need to duplicate code). (2) You don’t need to (and should generally not) explicitly specialise a function template when invoking it; that is, instead of `Search<T>(…)`, write `Search(…)`.

Comment: btw this question has two sides: How to write a function that finds a node in a tree? and How to return different type depening on a template parameter? And the answers are very likely very different

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are asking for *can* be done using `if constexpr` in C++17 and later, eg:

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T>
T BinarySearchTree::Search(Node *tree, int key) const {

    static_assert(
        std::is_same_v<T, bool> ||
        std::is_same_v<T, Node*> ||
        std::is_same_v<T, int>,
        "Invalid type specified");

    if (tree == nullptr) {
        if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, bool>)
            return false;
        }
        else if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, Node*>) {
            return nullptr;
        }
        else {
            return 0; // or throw an exception
        }
    }
    else if (key == tree->key) {
        if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, bool>)
            return true;
        }
        else if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, Node*>) {
            return tree;
        }
        else {
            return tree->key;
        }
    }
    else if (key < tree->key)
        return Search<T>(tree->left, key);
    else
        return Search<T>(tree->right, key);
}
```

Prior to C++17, a similar result can be accomplished using SFINAE, eg:

```
#include <type_traits>

Node* BinarySearchTree::InternalSearch(Node *tree, int key) const {
    if (tree == nullptr) {
        return nullptr;
    }
    else if (key == tree->key) {
        return tree;
    }
    else if (key < tree->key)
        return Search<T>(tree->left, key);
    else
        return Search<T>(tree->right, key);
}

template<typename T>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<T, bool>::value, T>::type
BinarySearchTree::Search(Node *tree, int key) const {
    return InternalSearch(tree, key) != nullptr;
}

template<typename T>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<T, Node*>::value, T>::type
BinarySearchTree::Search(Node *tree, int key) const {
   return InternalSearch(tree, key);
}

template<typename T>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<T, int>::value, T>::type
BinarySearchTree::Search(Node *tree, int key) const {
    tree = InternalSearch(tree, key);
    return tree != nullptr ? tree->key : 0 /* or throw an exception */;
}
```

Or, using template specialization, eg:

```
Node* BinarySearchTree::InternalSearch(Node *tree, int key) const {
    if (tree == nullptr) {
        return nullptr;
    }
    else if (key == tree->key) {
        return tree;
    }
    else if (key < tree->key)
        return Search<T>(tree->left, key);
    else
        return Search<T>(tree->right, key);
}

template<typename T>
T BinarySearchTree::Search(Node *tree, int key) const {
    // throw a suitable exception
}

template<>
bool BinarySearchTree::Search<bool>(Node *tree, int key) const {
    return InternalSearch(tree, key) != nullptr;
}

template<>
Node* BinarySearchTree::Search<Node*>(Node *tree, int key) const {
    return InternalSearch(tree, key);
}

template<>
int BinarySearchTree::Search<int>(Node *tree, int key) const {
    tree = InternalSearch(tree, key);
    return tree != nullptr ? tree->key : 0 /* or throw an exception */;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As noted in the comments, overloading based on return type is generally not a good idea from an API usability point of view (and since C++ doesn’t support it out of the box, it would require some tricks anyway).

Instead, use two distinct function names that are explicit about what they do:

```
Node* BinarySearchTree::Search(Node* tree, int key) const {
    // implement tree search
}

Node const* BinarySearchTree::Search(Node const* tree, int key) const {
    return const_cast<Node const*>(Search(const_cast<Node*>(tree), key));
}

bool BinarySearchTree::Contains(Node const* tree, int key) const {
    return Search(tree, key) != nullptr;
}
```

In addition, the public API of these functions should probably not have a `tree` parameter, since that’s only needed internally.